# Is 'puts it on speaker' the most natural way to expess when...?

Tags: phrase-request, idioms, idiomatic-language

> Jeff's phone rings. It's Billy. He doesn't pick the phone up, just answers, and **puts it on speaker**.
>
> Jeff: Hi, Billy.

Is 'puts it on speaker' the most natural way to express this? And is it enough without adding eg. '...phone' or '...mode' after 'speaker'? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's natural and idiomatic.

Comment: It depends if the person you're writing to is familiar with technology, because "speaker" on its own can mean several things, but "speakerphone" is unambiguous, so it is a question of whether you want to provide the extra information to aid understanding.

Answer (score 0):

"Put the phone on speaker" is correct. There's also another way to say that:

*Put the call [or the person] on speakerphone*

Source:

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-put-the-phone-on-speaker.2300666/